# 2 lights each controlled by separate switch

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm trying to put lights in a two door closet so that each side has its own light controlled by its own switch. Power comes into the first switch. I found a diagram that has the layout that I want except that I don't want a three way switch, each switch only controls its own light.[image] Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Very confusing about what you have **right now**. How many switches do you *currently* have? How many lights do you *currently* have? How do things *currently* work?

Comment: I would delete that picture since it will just confuse people.  What you need is to jump power from the first switch to the second, so each switch has power to control its own light.  The first switch will have the power cable(12/2 or 14/2), cable to the first light and another cable carrying power to the second switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it by routing the power from switch 1 to light 2 and then creating a switch loop for light 2.

[image]

UPDATE: code requires a neutral in the switch boxes so I have updated the diagram for the switch loop

UPDATE 2: changed reds to switched hot as per @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact suggestion

If it is easy to run a cable between the switches then you can wire it this way which wouldn't need any three wire

[image]

Comment: Well then you just use a 3 wire for the switch loop and cap the neutral - I will update the answer

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - good suggestion - updated diagram

Comment: Nice @FreeMan. Could you also stick with 2 wire but route power to Switch 2 from Switch 1 instead of to Light 2 as crip659 mentioned?

Comment: @fullerm yes of course you could - it depends on how close the two switches are two each other whether it would make more sense

Comment: @fullerm - added diagram for that wiring

Comment: Nice edits, DV removed, +1 now.